# Rails, custom finders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I want to be able to get an object using `find_by_id_or_name`, I feel like I saw another question like this but am trouble finding any resources on making my own finder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a class method to your model e.g.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_id_or_name(id_or_name)
    find :first, :conditions => ['id = ? or name = ?', id_or_name, id_or_name]
  end

  def self.find_all_by_id_or_name(id_or_name)
    find :all, :conditions => ['id = ? or name = ?', id_or_name, id_or_name]
  end
end
```

You will then by able to do

```
Model.find_by_id_or_name(id_or_name)
```

You can customise the method slightly depending on your requirements e.g. if you want to try by `id` first and then by `name` you could use `Model.exists?` first to see if there is matching record before doing a `find_by_name`. You could also look if `id_or_name` consisted of characters `0-9` and assume that was an `id` and only search by name if it contained other characters.