# How can I make a transient attribute available in dynamic finders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes, rails-models, dynamic-finders

I have a model **X** with an attribute **thedate** of type *datetime*.

**What is the slickest way to make thedate's year available for dynamic finders?**

Examples:

```
X.find_by_year(2012)
X.find_by_location_and_year('here', 2012)
X.find_by_year_and_name(2012, 'name')
X.find_all_by_year(2012)
...
```

So far I found [this custom finder approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516269/rails-custom-finders), but apparently that would require to implement each and every desired method manually. I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The best say is do a scope instead of trying using dynamic find. You can create the scope year and scope and use it

```
scope :year, lambda { |year| { ['thedate > ? AND thedate < ?', DateTime.now.change(:year => year).beginning_of_year, DateTime.now.change(:year => year).ending_of_year] }
```

You can use by `X.year(2012)`

Comment: With that approach I guess I'll need to implement any necessary combinations (e.g. year & name) manually. Right? It's probably a good option still.